# Make Horizontal Scrollbar Appear When Hidden Sidebar Appears and Pushes the Main Body Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage at http://www.domainandseo.com/project1/index.html.

When clicked on the Search Icon on the left side of the page, the sidebar menu appears, which pushes the rest of the page content to the right. Doing this causes almost half of the page to disappear, and no horizontal scrollbar appears.

I want a horizontal scrollbar to appear when the sidebar appears so that the visitor can scroll and see the rest of the page.

Any solution?

The CSS can be found at:
http://www.domainandseo.com/project1/css/style.css

My jquery script can be found at:
http://www.domainandseo.com/project1/js/jquery.sidr.min.js

Comment: What search icon...? (viewing on mobile)

Comment: at the very left side of the page there should be an icon...

Answer (score 0):

add a div (ex. wrapper) which contains your entire page with in it...and the css property for your `<div class="wrapper">` will be

```
 .wrapper{
  overflow:auto;
  }
```

to have only horizontal scroll bar

```
 .wrapper{
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: I tried the overflow: auto and the wrapper. But it does not work. Maybe because I'm using a slideout sidebar that appears through jquery?